# Importing from shared folder from react native

Tags: reactjs, import, react-native, package.json

I'm in the process of creating a monorepo to hold both my React web app and my React Native app as they share a lot of common code.

The setup i'm trying to get is:

```
Project  
|  
+-- web  
+-- native  
----|------ file.js (should be able to import from 'shared/file2.js')  
+-- shared  
----|------ file2.js  
----|------ package.json (with name="shared")  
+-- package.json
```

From folowing this post: https://blog.callstack.io/a-cure-for-relative-requires-in-react-native-2b263cecf0f6#.4g1o5inru I added a package.json file to the shared folder with:

```
{ "name": "shared" }
```

and am starting my native app from the package.json in the root folder like so:

```
"start-native": "./native/node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh"
```

But for some reason i'm getting the following error:
[image]

Any idea what i'm doing wrong or how I can achieve importing files in my RN app from a shared folder that is upstream?

**EDIT:**
A few details I forgot to mention.
The line giving me the error is (fake file names...):

```
// in native/file.js  
import { aFunctionName } from 'shared/file2'
```

Also tried adding a name in the package.json (name=proj-root) in the root level and importing like:

```
import { aFunctionName } from 'proj-root/shared/file2'
```

Thanks!
Uri

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: @HarshaVenkatram checkout the answer I posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up changing the folder structure as stated in @diegopartes answer.

In addition, I wanted to achieve the effect of being able to import from the shared folder using absolute paths from both my web and mobile directories.

For this I did the following:

**Web**
I moved my `webpack.config.js` to the root folder of the app. Inside webpack.config.js I have the following configuration the allows me to import files using absolute paths:

```
const path                = require('path');
const sharedPath          = path.join(__dirname, 'shared');

const config = {
...
resolve: {
    root: [sharedPath],
  },
...
}
```

now my shared folder acts as a root folder. Meaning, if I have

```
- shared  
-- reducers  
-- actions  
--- todos.js
```

I can do an `import { addTodo } from 'actions/todos'`

**Mobile**

Here I went by [this post](https://blog.callstack.io/a-cure-for-relative-requires-in-react-native-2b263cecf0f6#.xwcpvfcm6) which basically says:

Whichever folder you want to be able to import as root from, add a `package.json` file with `{ "name": "FOLDER_NAME" }`. So for to achieve the same import as in the web app:

```
- shared  
    -- reducers  
    -- actions  
    --- todos.js
    --- package.json
```

Where the `package.json` contents is:

```
{
  "name": "actions"
}
```

Now I can do the same import as I did in the web app from my mobile app files.

**EDIT**

Regarding `node_modules`, I use the same `package.json` for both web and mobile. In my `webpack.config` I have an array of all React Native packages an these are excluded from my vendor bundle file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will test this tonight.

Comment: Let's say I have an authActions.js inside actions folder. In the authActions.js, I am trying to import react-redux module. Where would you ideally install the node_modules that are referenced by the shared component. Would it be inside the shared directory or would it be inside the root directory of the project.

Comment: I updated the answer. I use the same package.json for both, in the root directory

Comment: Sharing ```package.json``` between mobile and web is fine until you reach a point (as I just have) that you cannot depend on the same version of ```react``` in both because of dependency conflict with other modules. Then you're screwed because mobile and web are glued together for no valid reason.

Answer (score 2):

To share code between web and native you should change how you are structuring your folders.

First start with a new project `react-native init myProject` this will create the default structure for RN apps.

```
myProject  
|  
+-- android
+-- ios
+-- index.android.js
+-- index.ios.js
...
```

Now create specific folders for web and shared code.

```
myProject  
|  
+-- android
+-- ios
+-- index.android.js
+-- index.ios.js
+-- web
+-- shared
----|------ index.js 
...
```

shared/index.js

```
function hi() {
    return 'hi';
}

module.exports = {
    hi: hi
};
```

index.ios.js

```
import { hi } from './shared/';
```

Comment: You are correct, it was missing the last / at `import { hi } from './shared/';` to load index.js inside that folder. It's working I can properly execute hi() from index.ios.js

Comment: There is a problem with this approach as well. Inside your web directory, create a simple proxy node server. Use some of the core node modules. RN throws an error for this too. Also, you are essentially including web inside mobile in this architecture, which I don't think is a good practice 

Comment: Actually, web and native architecture are totally separated. Only entry point for each platform is on root folder, you could for example run `create-react-app` to generate your web folder. I don't think it's bad approach, take a look at [this article](http://jkaufman.io/react-web-native-codesharing/).

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider to hoist [node_modules](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_loading_from_node_modules_folders)?

Moreover you can use [lerna](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/blob/master/doc/hoist.md) to achieve what you want instead of self-written solution.