# Importing from shared folder in react native @0.44.*

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to import code from parent of my react-native root.

There is [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-221815006) thread on react-native github repo which also discusses the same issue. The solution proposed in [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-221815006) comment does not seem to work with latest react-native.

Also [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12241) post here says it is not allowed to fetch from outside of your React Native Project root.

I have followed [this medium article](https://blog.callstack.io/a-cure-for-relative-requires-in-react-native-2b263cecf0f6) and other such sources which suggest similar way.

I am running - 
`"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",`

Folder Structure

```
  -- parent
    -- package.json {"name":'parent'}
    -- mobile
      -- app
        -- modules
          -- login
            -- Login (import { loginAPi } from 'parent/src/data/api')
    -- src
      -- package.json {"name": "source"}
    -- data
      -- package.json {"name": "data"}
      -- api
        -- package.json ({"name":"api"})
        -- index.js

packager console:

    error: bundling: UnableToResolveError: Unable to resolve module `parent/src/js/data/api` from `/Users/../../../../mobile/app/modules/login/Login.js`: 
    Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:
    /Users/../../../parent/mobile/node_modules/parent/src/js/data
    /Users/../../../parent/node_modules/parent/src/js/data
    /Users/../../../node_modules/parent/src/js/data
```

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40738675/importing-from-shared-folder-from-react-native#) - but the code for web application is stable and would like to achieve this without changing web application's current stable structure.

NOTE- Web application which is in `src` has been already developed and has considerable code, and the team is just starting with the react-native set up. We want to use the data part of the web application in the mobile.

Need help getting things right.